# roblox gamepass script not getting if the player has the pass

Tags: lua, roblox

i have an x3 coins gamepass, but when i print "hasPass", it returns nil

```
local debounce = false
local passID = 148667250

local function checkForPass(player)
    hasPass = false
    print(player.UserId)
    local success, message = pcall(function()
        hasPass = game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId, passID)
    end)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(checkForPass)

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if not debounce then
        print(hasPass)
        debounce = true
        if(hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")~=nil)then
            local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            local sound = script.Parent.CoinSFX:Clone()
            sound.Parent = player
            sound:Play()
            if not hasPass then
                player.leaderstats.Coins.Value += 1
            else
                player.leaderstats.Coins.Value += 3
            end
            script.Parent:Destroy()
            task.wait(0.5)
            player.CoinSFX:Destroy()
        end
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```

i already used the same pcall function on other gamepasses, so i dont know why its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure why i had to do this, but i created a script in server script storage that checks if the player has the pass and sets a boolean value to the result.

**server script storage**

```
local function checkForPass(player)
    local hasPass = false
    local success, message = pcall(function()
        hasPass = game:GetService("MarketplaceService"):UserOwnsGamePassAsync(player.UserId, 148667250)
    end)
    game.ServerStorage.Parts.Coin.HasPass.Value = hasPass
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(checkForPass)
```

**under the part**

```
local debounce = false

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if not debounce then
        debounce = true
        if(hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")~=nil)then
            local hasPass = script.Parent.HasPass.Value
            local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            local sound = script.Parent.CoinSFX:Clone()
            sound.Parent = player
            sound:Play()
            if not hasPass then
                player.leaderstats.Coins.Value += 1
            else
                player.leaderstats.Coins.Value += 3
            end
            script.Parent:Destroy()
            task.wait(0.5)
            player.CoinSFX:Destroy()
        end
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```